# can't set prepare for segue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have two controllers with `UINavigationController` (`UIViewController`(root) and `UITableViewController`). I need to click action at `UIViewController` and print something when move to `UITableViewController`

*TableViewController.swift*

```
func printString() {
    print("hello world")
}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sendData" {
        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navController.topViewController as! TableViewController
        controller.printString()
    }
}
```

And after click I see that

> Could not cast value of type 'myProjectName.TableViewController' (0x5a068) to 'UINavigationController' (0x17ffed4).

Why is that happening?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard as well?

Comment: [my storyboard](https://yadi.sk/d/cK_wx7n8j33Yr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sendData",
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewController {
                controller.printString()
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks like the destinationViewController is the TableViewController.